# Função retornando apenas um valor

Tags: python, funções, lista, testes-de-unidade, dicionário

Estou fazendo um programa em Python e preciso implementar uma função. A função recebe como entrada dois parâmetros: *Um **​dicionário** contendo como chave o​ nome ​de um funcionário e como valor uma lista contendo ​email​, ​salário-base​ e ​cargo​ desse funcionário.
O **​nome​** de um funcionário.*

---

A função deve retornar como resultado o​ salário líquido do funcionário. O salário é calculado de acordo com regras para cada cargo.

- Desenvolvedor, desconto de 15%, se salário >= 2000, senão desconto de 5%.
- Analista, desconto de 20%, se salário >= 3500, senão desconto de 10%.
- Gerente, desconto de 25%, se salário >= 4000, senão desconto de 15% .

---

No entanto quando eu implemento o código eu e rodo o arquivo de teste, ele me retorna um único resultado: *Resultado da Função: 2550.0*

Como faço para que ele retorne o resultado esperado para cada função e não apenas 2550.0?

---

**Função que implementei**

```
def calcular_salario(dicionario, nome):
    for nome in dicionario:
        if dicionario[nome][2] == 'DESENVOLVEDOR':
            if dicionario[nome][1] >= 2000:
                resultado = dicionario[nome][1] - (dicionario[nome][1] * .15)
            else:
                resultado = dicionario[nome][1] - (dicionario[nome][1] * 0.05)

        if dicionario[nome][2] == 'ANALISTA':
            if dicionario[nome][1] >= 3500:
                resultado = dicionario[nome][1] - (dicionario[nome][1] * .20)
            else:
                resultado = dicionario[nome][1] - (dicionario[nome][1] * .10)

        if dicionario[nome][2] == 'GERENTE':
            if dicionario[nome][1] >= 4000:
                resultado = dicionario[nome][1] - (dicionario[nome][1] * .25)
            else:
                resultado = dicionario[nome][1] - (dicionario[nome][1] * .15)
    return resultado
```

**Arquivo de teste** - **Não posso modificar**

```
from ac02 import calcular_salario


dicionario = {'marcilio': ['marcilio@email.com', 5000.00, 'DESENVOLVEDOR'],
              'pedro': ['pedro@email.com', 2000.00, 'DESENVOLVEDOR'],
              'carlos': ['carlos@email.com', 1000.00, 'DESENVOLVEDOR'],
              'roberto': ['roberto@email.com', 5000.00, 'ANALISTA'],
              'renata': ['renata@email.com', 3500.00, 'ANALISTA'],
              'angelica': ['angelica@email.com', 1000.00, 'ANALISTA'],
              'amanda': ['amanda@email.com', 8000.00, 'GERENTE'],
              'ricardo': ['ricardo@email.com', 4000.00, 'GERENTE'],
              'fernanda': ['fernanda@email.com', 3000.00, 'GERENTE'],
              'marcos': ['marcos@email.com', 800.00, 'ESTAGIARIO']}

try:
    resultado = calcular_salario(dicionario, 'marcilio')
    assert resultado == 4250.0
    print('CORRETO')
except AssertionError:
    print('ERRO:')
    print(' Resultado esperado: 4250.0')
    print(' Resultado da Função:', resultado)

try:
    resultado = calcular_salario(dicionario, 'pedro')
    assert resultado == 1700.0
    print('CORRETO')
except AssertionError:
    print('ERRO:')
    print(' Resultado esperado: 1700.0')
    print(' Resultado da Função:', resultado)

try:
    resultado = calcular_salario(dicionario, 'carlos')
    assert resultado == 950.0
    print('CORRETO')
except AssertionError:
    print('ERRO:')
    print(' Resultado esperado: 950.0')
    print(' Resultado da Função:', resultado)

try:
    resultado = calcular_salario(dicionario, 'roberto')
    assert resultado == 4000.0
    print('CORRETO')
except AssertionError:
    print('ERRO:')
    print(' Resultado esperado: 4000.0')
    print(' Resultado da Função:', resultado)

try:
    resultado = calcular_salario(dicionario, 'renata')
    assert resultado == 2800.0
    print('CORRETO')
except AssertionError:
    print('ERRO:')
    print(' Resultado esperado: 2800.0')
    print(' Resultado da Função:', resultado)

try:
    resultado = calcular_salario(dicionario, 'angelica')
    assert resultado == 900.0
    print('CORRETO')
except AssertionError:
    print('ERRO:')
    print(' Resultado esperado: 900.0')
    print(' Resultado da Função:', resultado)

try:
    resultado = calcular_salario(dicionario, 'amanda')
    assert resultado == 6000.0
    print('CORRETO')
except AssertionError:
    print('ERRO:')
    print(' Resultado esperado: 6000.0')
    print(' Resultado da Função:', resultado)

try:
    resultado = calcular_salario(dicionario, 'ricardo')
    assert resultado == 3000.0
    print('CORRETO')
except AssertionError:
    print('ERRO:')
    print(' Resultado esperado: 3000.0')
    print(' Resultado da Função:', resultado)

try:
    resultado = calcular_salario(dicionario, 'fernanda')
    assert resultado == 2550.0
    print('CORRETO')
except AssertionError:
    print('ERRO:')
    print(' Resultado esperado: 2550.0')
    print(' Resultado da Função:', resultado)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema começa aqui:

```
def calcular_salario(dicionario, nome):
    for nome in dicionario:
```

Na primeira linha, você define que a função possui o parâmetro `nome`, mas na segunda linha, usa essa variável no *loop*, ou seja o valor que foi recebido é sobrescrito a cada iteração do mesmo.

Mas na verdade você não precisa fazer um *loop* por todos os registros do dicionário. Perceba a estrutura do mesmo:

```
dicionario = {'marcilio': ['marcilio@email.com', 5000.00, 'DESENVOLVEDOR'],
              'pedro': ['pedro@email.com', 2000.00, 'DESENVOLVEDOR'],
              'carlos': ['carlos@email.com', 1000.00, 'DESENVOLVEDOR'],
              etc...
```

Ou seja, o nome é a chave, então basta fazer `dicionario[nome]`, que você obtém a lista contendo os demais dados do funcionário. Assim:

```
def calcular_salario(dicionario, nome):
    email, salario, cargo = dicionario[nome]
    if cargo == 'DESENVOLVEDOR':
        if salario >= 2000:
            return salario * 0.85
        else:
            return salario * 0.95

    if cargo == 'ANALISTA':
        if salario >= 3500:
            return salario * 0.8
        else:
            return salario * 0.9

    if cargo == 'GERENTE':
        if salario >= 4000:
            return salario * 0.75
        else:
            return salario * 0.85
```

Repare que já posso pegar os elementos da lista e colocá-los em variáveis:

```
email, salario, cargo = dicionario[nome]
```

Como todas as listas tem exatamente 3 elementos, não haverá problema em fazer assim.

Depois basta verificar as condições e retornar o valor. Repare que posso usar `return` em qualquer ponto, pois um `return` retorna o valor e sai da função (ou seja, ele não executa mais nada depois), e é exatamente o que preciso: se cheguei na condição que preciso, retorno o valor e pronto.

Também mudei o cálculo das porcentagens. Afinal, se há um desconto de 10%, o que sobra é 90% do salário, então basta fazer `salario * 0.9` (o mesmo vale para os demais casos).

---

Obs: como o `email` não é usado na função, existe a convenção de se usar `_` como nome da variável, justamente para indicar que é uma informação que não é usada:

```
_, salario, cargo = dicionario[nome]
```

Apesar de não ser usado na função, ainda sim é necessário colocá-lo, para que o Python saiba que o primeiro elemento da lista deve ser colocado ali (assim o segundo e terceiro elementos são colocados corretamente nas variáveis `salario` e `cargo`).